# Colocar Itens em Scroll

Tags: html, css

Olá! Estou tentando criar uma scroll horizontal com determinados itens. Porém ele quebra pra baixo ao invés de continuar ao lado. Quero fazer um efeito scroll para mostrar mais conteúdo ao lado.

```css
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.conteudo {
    height: 435px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 15px #888888;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.novos-titulos {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 10px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="conteudo">

                <h2>Novos Títulos</h2>

                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>


                <?php

                    include_once 'conexao.php';

                    $sql = "select * from perfil ORDER BY idperfil DESC LIMIT 7";

                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                ?>

                <article class="novos-titulos">

<h3><a href="perfil.php?idperfil=<?php echo $row["idperfil"];?>"><?php echo mb_strimwidth($row["titulo"], 0, 20, "..." ); ?></a></h3>

                    <a href="perfil.php?idperfil=<?php echo $row["idperfil"];?>"><img src="img/<?php echo $row["capa"]; ?>" alt=""></a>
                    <span>Total: <?php echo $row["episodios"]; ?></span>

                </article>

  <?php } mysqli_close($con);?>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oliver, disponibilizar executáveis com php incluído nunca é uma boa opção, se perceber ao clicar em executar absolutamente nada funciona como deveria funcionar. Ou seja, o código disponibilizado não funciona para absolutamente nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É impossível usar seu código disponibilizado então criei um exemplo simples para que você entenda.

O problema que você está tendo pode ser facilmente resolvido como estilo `white-space: nowrap;`, bascicamente o que ele faz é dizer para o navegador que aquela determinada div **NUNCA** irá possuir quebra de linha. Depois adicionamos as opções de overflow.

Eixo **X** da div:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

Estamos dizendo que tudo que 'transbordar' horizontalmente a div será exibido em forma de scroll.

Eixo **Y** da div:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Estamos dizendo que tudo que 'transbordar' verticalmente a div não será exibido.
*Você não precisa se preocupar com conteúdo não sendo exibido. com o `nowrap` incluso o eixo Y nunca sofrerá alteração.*

```css
.quad{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.scroll{
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 30%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='scroll'>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
<div class='quad'>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom, só que acredito que ele vai precisar de um javascript pra fazer funcionar o scroll pelo mouse.